# HTTP Status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a registration form in spring mvc. UserProfile model is responsible for registration which has 1 to 1 relationship with Password model and many to many relationship with Role model.

**UserProfile model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profile")
public class UserProfile {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_profile_id")
    private Integer userProfileId;

    @Column(name="user_name",length=30,unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="sex")
    private String sex;

    @Column(name="contact")
    private String contact;

    @Column(name="image_path")
    private String imagePath;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_join_profile", 
         joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_profile") }, 
         inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role") })
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Role> role = new ArrayList<Role>();

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="password")
   private Password password;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="postGiver",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private List<DashBoard> dashBoardList;


   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name = "message_join_user", 
         joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_profile") }, 
         inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "message_id") })
   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<Message>();


   +All attribute's getters & setters


 }
```

**Role model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role {
      @Id 
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name="role_id")
      private Integer roleId;

       +All attribute's getters & setters
}
```

**Password Model:**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="password")
 public class Password {
       @Id 
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Column(name="password_id")
       private Integer passwordId;

       @Column(name="password")
       private String password;

       +All attribute's getters & setters
  }
```

If i post a form related with UserProfile model,following error is shown

**HTTP Status 400 -The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**

It does not enter into post method of controller.

When i try with other models(like Role model),it works.

What is the problem with this UserProfile model that shows the error.

**Form:**

```
<form:form action="reg" method="POST" >
<input type="submit"/>**There is no field here cause i just want to hit     
                  controller's method**
</form:form>
```

**Controller's method:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/reg",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public void reg(Model model,@ModelAttribute UserProfile userProfile){
    System.out.print("sssssss");//this is not being printed,which should be
}
```